# identify and select multiple rows based on a column's date value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out how identify all date values in a column of a table(older than 1 week from today) and select them.
I was struggling with trying some `range.find` methods with `findnext` but cannot get anything to remotely work.
My initial thoughts on this were to identify all these rows of data, select them and create a new table with them (which I will most likely use as a pivot cache).

Just a thought as I'm writing this, would it be much easier to use vba to filter the table and copy/paste? Going to try this in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I struggled so much with this, the outcome is pretty simple.
I'm just filtering the dates I don't want and deleting the data. While I still haven't found an easy way to identify network days, this seems to be doing exactly what I need.

```
Sub Filter_Week_Old()
Dim t As Date

t = Format([Today()] - 7, "mm/dd/yy")
    With Range("Table1")
    .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=">" & t
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .AutoFilter field:=4
    End With
End Sub
```